# Python: Set a quotechar for csv.DictWriter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to set a quotechar for csv.DictWriter() field names similar to how you can set a quotechar with csv.reader()? I am specifically interested in surrounding non-numeric field name entries with the specified quotechar defined by the `quote` variable below.

I am trying to get

```
    fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    separator = ','
    quote = '"'
    table = [{'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 11, 'e': 14, 'd': 13}]

    with open('output1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames, delimiter = separator)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in table:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

to output

```
"a","b","c","d","e"
10,11,12,13,14
```

when `quote = '"'` instead of

```
a,b,c,d,e
10,11,12,13,14
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
separator = ','
quote = '"'
table = [{'a': 10, 'c': 12, 'b': 11, 'e': 14, 'd': 13}]

with open('output1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        csvfile,
        fieldnames=fieldnames,
        delimiter=separator,
        quotechar=quote,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,
    )
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in table:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

i think you are looking for [csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

Comment: Adding quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC alone doesn't do the trick but referencing csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC led me to find out how you can define what the quote used is. Adding quotechar = quote, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC as arguments for csv.DictWriter seems to be doing exactly what I need. I'll run a couple tests tonight and in the morning and accept an answer soon.

Answer (score -1):

You can, but you need two different writers, since apparently you want to quote the header but not the data rows:

```
with open('output1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    quoted = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=separator, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    quoted.writeheader()

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=separator)
    for row in table:
        writer.writerow(row)
```